# Duplication of TEXTINCLUDE sections in .rc file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, resource-file

In my .rc file I found that I have the 3 TEXTINCLUDE sections repeated twice, with different content. When I open "Resource Includes", only the includes from the first 3 sections are shown. I've tweaked the .rc a long time ago, so it maybe is a leftover from that.

Can I safely remove the second 3 sections?

I've pasted this from my .rc file, you can see how the TEXTINCLUDE sections are repeated (i.e. "3 TEXTINCLUDE" is followed by "1 TEXTINCLUDE".

```
1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "#include ""res/Pngs.h""\r\n"
    "#include ""res/PngsNag.h""\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.rc""      // Standard components\r\n"
    "#include ""res/MyProject.rc2""\r\n"
    "#include ""res/Pngs.rc2""\r\n"
    "#include ""res/PngsNag.rc2""\0"
END

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)\r\n"
    "#ifdef _WIN32\r\n"
    "LANGUAGE 9, 1\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(1252)\r\n"
    "#endif //_WIN32\r\n"
    "#include ""res\\MyProject.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""afxres.rc""         // Standard components\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
    "\0"
END
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is gunk that's generated by the graphical resource editor built into Visual Studio.  It doesn't have any effect at runtime, it merely saves state for the editor.  You'll run a serious risk of breaking the editor when you mess with it.  Which is okay if you *never* use the resource editor and always manage resources with a text editor.

There's a bit of background info in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk(v=vs.140).aspx):

> The following describes how Visual C++ maintains this information in a .RC file. You do not need this information to use Visual C++, but it may enhance your understanding so that you can more confidently use the Set Includes feature.
>
> Each of the above three types of Set Includes information is stored in the .RC file in two forms: (1) as #include or other directives interpretable by the Resource Compiler, and (2) as special TEXTINCLUDE resources interpretable only by Visual C++.
>
> The purpose of the TEXTINCLUDE resource is to safely store Set Include information in a form that is readily presentable in Visual C++'s Set Includes dialog box. TEXTINCLUDE is a resource type defined by Visual C++. Visual C++ recognizes three specific TEXTINCLUDE resources that have the resource identification numbers 1, 2 and 3:

```
TEXTINCLUDE resource ID     Type of Set Includes information
        1                   Symbol Header File
        2                   Read-Only Symbol Directives
        3                   Compile-Time Directives
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one set of `TEXTINCLUDE`'s is needed. You just need to decide what set works better for you.